# Периодически отлетает и восстанавливается связь по SSH с сервером

Tags: linux, сеть, ip

Использую 2 машины win10 и ubuntu server оба за маршрутизатором, на сервере отключил файервол и putty стал подключатся.

Но спустя часа 3 снова перестал подключатся, потом прошло еще часа 2 снова подключился, все это время ничего вообще не трогал сервер как стоял включенный так я его и не трогал.

Ошибка `Network error: Connection time out`.

Cитуация такая PuTTY то подключается то нет, я нагуглил информацию что могу попадать в какой то бан лист своими частыми попытками подключится, где его найти этот бан лист или причина в другом?

Comment: К серверу значит вы [таки подключились](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756903/213987)? )) Прямо хоть пиши эталонный ответ-закрывашку по бытовым темам администрирования... По теме текущего вопроса: а не запущена ли служба fail2ban? Не настроена ли гибернация на сервере или уход сетевой карты в спящий режим?

Comment: Знаете все же я думаю это мой фаервол темнит, потому что когда его отключаю `sudo ufw disable` - мне пишет что фаервол отключен, но когда я сразу после этого пишу `sudo service ufw status` мне пишет `active` значит все же это не в сетевухе дело, хотя тоже не исключено, но для начала думаю нужно окончательно с фаерволом разобраться. Так как же все таки полностью отключить ufw? не знаю не хочется новый вопрос создавать.PS Правила для 22 пробовал добавлять он пишет что все ОК но ве ровно не пропускает.

Comment: Хм, я больше CentOS юзаю, но принцип тот же: когда вы делаете disable демону -- вы просто отключаете автозапуск. А сам демон может при этом находится в любом статусе. Есть команда `sudo service uwf stop` -- вот она останавливает (вместо stop может быть start, restart)

Comment: Уже даже не знаю что делать, я снес ufw и установил заново, пока не включал теперь статус inactive, значит он точно не работает, но подключение все ровно не проходит. Может я что то изначально не правильно делаю, хотя пару раз заработало, ip получаю по dhcp пишу `ifconfig` и в putty вбиваю ip сетевухи и порт 22 все до этого 2 раза подключилось а потом перестало. Кстати ping c сервера например до гугла идет а с моей win машины до сервера не идет.

Comment: Так у вас поди ICMP трафик не разрешен.

Comment: @AK про пинг я для примера сказал, главная проблема ssh, ведь ssh по tcp работает что может еще и tcp трафик быть запрещен, думаю вряд ли.