# Не работает ssh подключение

Tags: linux, сеть, ip

Использую 2 машины, первая win вторая ubuntu server. Настроил подключение по ssh через Putty, подключение работало, проверял пару раз, но после перезагрузки win машины на которой стоит Putty он перестал подключатся по ssh, ошибка: таймаут. Сервер не трогал. Мои предположения: Может быть дело в адресах ведь ip я получаю по dhcp но в роутере порт проброшен и мак привязан к ip сервера. `ifconfig` постоянно проверяю на сервере ip не меняется значит с ip вроде все нормально. Фаервол выключен, iptables правило добавлено. У кого какие предположения?

Answer (score 0):

1) проверь через телнет доступность порта. например telnet    someipaddress 22. если есть возможность с разных машин (можно и с    телефона)

2) отключить антивирусные продукты временно (редко но    бывает симантек и другие порождают фантомные проблемы)

3) если есть  возможность покажи iptables -L

Comment: в iptables првило добалил, было бы удобнее картинкой отправить но не знаю как тут картинки загружать, вот что показал iptables `ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh` антивирусы вроде никакие не установлены. сейчас буду с телнетом разбираться раньше с ним дело не имел

Comment: вот мои предыдущие вопросы по этой теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756903/Не-работает-сеть-между-компьютерами , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757620/Периодически-отлетает-и-восстанавливается-связь-по-ssh-с-сервером

Comment: сейчас ничего не трагая само стало работать, но соединение периодически слелает и не подключается снова, вот я хотел бы знать причину это неоднозначности.

Comment: покажи вывод iptables -L. у тебя не может быть хоста с таким же ip ? пробовал arping или аналог когда наблюдаются проблемы ?

Comment: `sudo iptables -L` выводит огромную кучу всего там даже в одну страницу все не уместится, и в один комментарий точно не влезет

Comment: для этого есть сервисы такие как pastebin. если правил много и это не ты это наводит на мысль что устанавилвал пакеты которые конфигурируют сеть за тебя, например KVM с firewalld